# Characterizing vanishing étale cohomology in higher degrees

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a scheme and suppose that the étale cohomology  $H^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ vanishes for all quasi coherent sheaves $\mathcal{F}$ and $i > 0$. Clearly if $X = \text{Spec}(k)$ for an algebraically closed field this holds. But can we also characterize the schemes for which this occurs?

Certainly there should be no nontrivial étale covers.

Comment: You've written etale cohomology in the title but you haven't specified the cohomology you want in the body.

Comment: If $X$ is quasi-compact then this is equivalent to $X$ being affine? Quasi-coherent sheaves have the same etale cohomology as they do cohomology for the Zariski site, and so this is just Serre's criterion for affineness.